# How to exclude java classes from being compiled in maven with annotation

Tags: java, maven, annotations

I already have a **working** solution where I can specify with maven which classes to not compile when using a particular maven profile.

But I would like to use a general solution and use an annotation instead

The current solution that I have is like

```
<plugin>
    <!-- Exclude some web services used only for internal testing -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <optimize>true</optimize>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/something/*ClassPattern.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <testExcludes>
            <exclude>**/something/*ClassPatternTest.java</exclude>
        </testExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But Some thing like

```
@NotCompiledForProduction
```

would be rather nice on top of a class.

It seems to me that this might be hard (or impossible to do) without changing maven's behaviour. That is not the scope here. And this kind of annotation

Comment: Why is that nicer? I prefer the maven approach. IT doesnt seem good practice to store build information in the class itself. What if you decide you do want to build that class? You now need a code change.

Comment: Put them in src/test/java.  Default maven config will know they are test classes.

Comment: @cowls : It is nicer because it is more generic. All the new things that I want to add to my system but don't want them exposed would get this annotation. No meddling around with pom file. I guess it's a matter of style.

Comment: I think sbk is probably right here, if you dont want them in production they shouldnt be in src/main/java. Assuming they are just test classes, put them in src/test/java and Maven will handle it.

Comment: well these are test services for internal use (internal consumer who gets the entire app as it is shipped, plus these extra services). So putting them in test package doesn't do good. I have a solution now with a name convention and skipping the war packing of those classes works for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (I assume) use an annotation to determine what source code gets presented to the java compiler, because you need to compile the source code in the first place to process the annotation.

It seems like you need to create different modules in your maven project: one that generates a jar file with the production code, and one module that generates a jar file with testing implementation with a dependency on the production artifact.

If the code really does need to be in the same maven module, then the code should *always* be compiled. You can however use `maven-jar-plugin` to create multiple artifacts at the `package` phase: the default *`artifactId`.jar*, and an *`artifactId`-test-lib.jar* artifact. You can do this by specifying multiple executions for the plugin, and using `<includes>` and `<excludes>` to split the jar files as required.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
<build> <plugins>
  <!-- Run annotation processors on src/main/java sources -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>process</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <!-- Disable annotation processors during normal compilation -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins> </build>
```

Comment: that defeats the purpose, I will try to clarify the question a bit more .