# Excluding NullnessChecker annotation processor for generated code

Tags: maven-compiler-plugin, checker-framework

I am integrating the Nullness Checker from the checker Framework to our Java project built with Maven. I configured the annotation processor for `maven-compiler-plugin` plugin. Everything works fine except that I don't want it run through the generated code.

Something along the lines of excluding the use of these annotation processors for code in `target` directory or for a specific java package could help, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

I also tried to find a configuration for the Nullness Checker itself to exclude directories or java packages. Again I couldn't find anything.

Here's my plugin config:

```html
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>checker</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
    <annotationProcessors>
      <annotationProcessor>org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker</annotationProcessor>
    </annotationProcessors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude certain files from the `javac` invocation that runs an annotation processor, that is a question about Maven that already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939276/how-to-exclude-java-classes-from-being-compiled-in-maven-with-annotation).

If you want to run `javac` on all files when running the annotation processor, but you want to suppress all warnings regarding certain files, use the [`-skipDefs`](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#askipdefs) command-line argument.  Using `-skipDefs` makes the Nullness Checker issue the same warnings as if it had not been run on certain files.

Comment: `-skipDefs` was what I was looking for. Thanks!